# SQL cartesion product with multiple column subquery,Unknown column issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, mysql-workbench

```
SELECT 
   daf.id as affiliate_id,
   daf.name as affiliate_name,
   dal.name as allocation_name,
   dal.id as allocation_id,
   dal.allocation,dal.price
FROM 
     degreeamerica.affiliates daf, degreeamerica.allocations dal
JOIN 
     (select pap.lead_price,pap.live, pap.allocation_id,pap.affiliate_id from paul.affiliates_price pap) pafp  
ON (dal.id=pafp.allocation_id and daf.id=pafp.affiliate_id) 
ORDER BY daf.id;
```

Issue: Unknows column daf.id in on clause
I have this column but still it is saying unknown column. Please help!!!!

Comment: Can you include the relevant tables as well, so the error can be reproduced?

Comment: You need the schema?

Answer (score 0):

I believe in mySQL you can order by the alias of the field.

```
ORDER BY affiliate_id;
```